# Unable to register uninstalled web hook in shopify react app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, shopify-app

// While i am trying to register uninstalled app webhook i am getting an error below is my code to register uninstalled webhook while other hooks i am creating are working fine

```
const registrationUninstall = await registerWebhook({
address: `${HOST}/uninstalled`,
topic: 'app/uninstalled',
accessToken,
shop,
apiVersion: ApiVersion.October19
});

if (registrationUninstall.success) {
console.log('Successfully registered uninstall webhook!');
} else {
console.log('Failed to register uninstall webhook', registrationUninstall.result);
}


// This is the error i am getting while i am trying to register uninstalled app webhook:- 

Failed to register uninstall webhook {
errors: [
{
  message: 'Parse error on "/" (error) at [3, 44]',
  locations: [Array]
}
]
}
```

Comment: Try to dump GraphQL query and paste in the GraphiQL Shopify app, that might help to figure out the issue... as it seems dynamically generated query making some error

Comment: There is a different way to register web-hooks when creating shopify react app. Please see my below code. It is fixed now

Comment: That's nice. new thing to keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are going to create shopify react app and want to register uninstall web-hooks all you need to give topic name with capital letters followed by underscore between keywords please refer below code for uninstall web hooks registration :- 

// Uninstalled Web Hook :- 
   const registrationUninstall = await registerWebhook({
     address: `${HOST}/webhooks/uninstalled_app`,
     topic: 'APP_UNINSTALLED',
     accessToken,
     shop,
     apiVersion: ApiVersion.October19
  });

  if (registrationUninstall.success) {
     console.log('Successfully registered uninstall webhook!');
  } else {
     console.log('Failed to register uninstall webhook', registrationUninstall.result);
  }
```